# react.js page refresh issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Page not working after refresh, but working fine when clicked on the links in react.js. This Problem occurs after deployment. I deployed my app using **npm run build**.

Here is my index.js file:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
    import './index.css';
    import App from './App';
    import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
    import { CONFIG } from './config';
    /**Import Components**/
    import Dashboard from './components/dashboard';
    import NetRights from './components/net_rights';
    import CommonRights from './components/common_rights';
    import Sales from './components/sales';
    import Finance from './components/finance';


    const Root = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Router history={browserHistory}>
                    <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/`} component={App}>
                        <IndexRoute component={Dashboard}/>
                        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/folder_name/dashboard`} component={Dashboard}/>
                        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/folder_name/net_rights`} component={NetRights}/>
                        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/folder_name/common_rights`} component={CommonRights}/>
                        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/folder_name/sales`} component={Sales}/>
                        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/folder_name/finance`} component={Finance}/>
                    </Route>
                </Router>
            </div>
        )
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById('root'));

    registerServiceWorker();
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rtapp09",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "homepage": "/folder_name/"
}
```

Comment: what is the code of the script `npm run build` ? (check package.json/ scripts)

Comment: Thanks! I just update my question and added package.json.

Comment: can you please explain more,, what do you mean by `not working` and what do you mean by `clicked on the links` ? do you mean that hot reload is not working?

Comment: I have a sidebar with different links in my app. When i click on that links, it open that link and show all content. After that link is open when i refresh my page using F5 button from keyboard, it says page not found.

Comment: you didn't add 'react-router' module to your pakcage.json. I guess you installed it globally (-g)

Comment: Yes 'react-router' module not added in package.json, because i installed it manually using command line. But its available inside my node_modules directory.

Comment: don't use Router, for some reasons you have to user HashRouter like that: import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
instead of import {Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: you need to re-write your urls . tell me what server are you trying to use to deploy it?

Comment: I use npm run build for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind to have # inside of your URL, just use this import:

import {HashRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

With Hash History instead of Browser History, your URL for the about page would look something like this: http://example.com/#/about The part after the hash (#) symbol is not sent to the server. So the server only sees http://example.com/ and sends the index page as expected. React-Router will pick up the #/about part and show the correct page.

Downsides:

'ugly' URLs
Server-side rendering is not possible with this approach. As far as Search Engine Optimization (SEO) is concerned, your website consists of a single page with hardly any content on it.